# Using dplyr to add new columns based on an other data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I got two data frames:

[image]

Now I would like to add a new field to the first data frame that contains the Result column from the second data frame but ***only*** the result that is in the row for each person that has the lowest date.

So the resulting data frame should look like:

[image]

Is it possible to do this in dplyr's `mutate()` function or any other way in R? I tried looking into how to solve this issue but I can't seem to figure it out. Hope any of you people knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can select row with minimum value of `Date` for each `name` and `left_join` with `df1`.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  left_join(df2 %>%
              group_by(Name) %>%
              slice(which.min(Date)), by = 'Name')
```

Comment: Let me go give this a try. No clue why someone downvoted this post.

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say lack of reproducible example and posting image of data.

Comment: I see you are not taking the first given result based on date but on lowest score. It should take the Result that has the lowest date instead.

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`, we can do a join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, Result := Result[which.min(Date)],on = .(Name), by = .EACHI]
df1
#   Name Age Country Result
#1: Jack  45      NL      5
#2: Lisa  43     USA     NA
#3:  Ben  12       D      9
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Name = c("Jack", "Lisa","Ben"), Age = c(45, 43, 12), 
    Country = c("NL", "USA", "D"))
df2 <- data.frame(Name = c("Jack", "Jack", "Ben"), Result = c(6, 5, 9),
     Date = as.Date(c("2002-06-09", "2001-07-23", "2001-07-23")))
```